# Regular Expression matching in ElasticSearch not working as expected

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to search for a specific string in a message, such that the string can have following values:

- "program startup process begin"
- "program shutdown process begin"
- "program recovery process begin"
- "program shutdown process end"

I'm using the following query to try to find these messages:

```
GET /my_index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "regexp":{
            "message": "program.*process.*"
        }
    }
}
```

The above search is not giving any results at all. Though if I use

```
GET /my_index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "regexp":{
            "message": "program.*"
        }
    }
}
```

it gives all the expected matches (though many more than what I want).

What am I doing wrong with the regex expression?

Comment: Can you post your mapping for `my_index`?

Comment: Also, does `process.*` work? I think it's probably because the analyzer is splitting it into terms and the regexp is being applied to each term individually. See the note all the way at the bottom of this page: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_wildcard_and_regexp_queries.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use a `match_phrase` query with a slop of 1. That's much more performant than using regexp queries:

```
POST test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "text": {
        "query": "program process",
        "slop": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```